# c++ fstream write doesn't work with binary file without seekg and seekp

Tags: c++, file, fstream

i need to read and write to the same file in sequential order (without seekg and seekp)
but for some reason .write doesn't work !

here is my class

```
class student
{
    int id ; 
    char name[20]  ;
    int m1 , m2 , m3 ; 
public:
    student()
    {
    }
    student(int idd , char*n , int mm1 , int mm2 , int mm3 )
    {
        id = idd ; 
        strcpy(name , n); 
        m1 = mm1 ; 
        m2 = mm2 ; 
        m3 = mm3 ; 
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"student id : "<<id<<endl<<"student name : "<<name<<endl<<"mark 1 : "<<m1<<endl<<"mrak 2 : "<<m2<<endl<<"mark 3 : "<<m3<<endl ;
    }
    void get()
    {
        cout<<"enter student id : " ; 
        cin>>id ; 
        cout<<"enter student name : " ; 
        cin.ignore() ; 
        cin.get(name , 20) ; 
        cout<<"enter student's mark 1 :" ; 
        cin>>m1 ; 
        cout<<"enter student's mark 2 :" ; 
        cin>>m2 ; 
        cout<<"enter student's mark 3 :" ; 
        cin>>m3 ; 


    }


};
```

and here is my main function :

```
   int main()
{
       fstream file("f://records.dat" , ios::out | ios::in  |ios::binary ) ; 
    if(!file)
    {
        cout<<"Error !";
        int z ; 
        cin>>z ;
        return 4 ; 

    }


    modify(file);

    int x ; 
    cin>>x ; 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

and here is my function :

```
void modify(fstream &file)
{   
    int recnum  ;
    cout<<"enter the number of the record to be modified : " ; 
    cin>>recnum ;
    file.seekg(0) ; 
    file.seekp(0);
    student s1 ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<recnum-1 ; i++) 
    {
        file.read((char *) &s1 , sizeof(s1)) ;  
    }
int x = file.tellp() ;
    int y = file.tellg() ; 
    cout<<x<<endl<<y<<endl ;   
student s2 ;
s2.get() ; 
    file.write((char *) &s2 , sizeof(student))
    x = file.tellp() ;
    y = file.tellg() ;
    cout<<x<<endl<<y<<endl ;   

    file.flush() ; 
        file.seekg(0 , ios::beg);
    if(file.eof())
    {
        cout<<"error !" ; 
        int x ; 
        cin>>x ; 
    }

        while(file.read((char *) &s1 , sizeof(student)))
    {
        s1.show() ; 
    }
}
```

it seems that the write function int the method modify doesn't work so please could anybody help me ?????

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Can you elaborate on what the code is supposed to do, what you've tried so far, etc.?

Comment: @templatetypedef okay , the .write function in the modify function is the one not working when i try to modify any records in the file it simply doesn't and it keeps the old value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was compiling in visual studio 2010 , and when i took the same code and compiled it on other  ides like code blocks , it works fine and outputs the expected results i think it is a .Net issue or something !

Comment: Different compilers can use different implementations of bidirectional stream positioning. I don't think this is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that bidirection file streams all hold a joint buffer where input and output both have an affect on the next character to be read *and* written. For instance, while reading is done, the *output* position indicator will also be incremented by the amount of characters read.

In your `modify` function, you perform a `write` directly after performing a `read` without setting the output position indicator back to 0. This should always be done in order to receive expected results.

The same goes for output followed by input: Don't forget to set the `seekg` position indicator as well.